# ira_laser_tools merger node is not subscribing lidar topics

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to merge 3 lidar feed. Lidar point cloud topics are working fine. When I tried to run ira_laser_tool node it is working but it is not subscribing to my lidar topis? I have add rostopic list, rosnode info. Also, asking for other tools like laser_merger?

rostopic list:

```
rostopic list
/laserscan_multi_merger/parameter_descriptions
/laserscan_multi_merger/parameter_updates
/merged_cloud
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan_multi
/sensor1/points
/sensor2/points
/sensor3/points
/tf
/tf_static
```

rosnode info:

```
rosnode info /laserscan_multi_merger 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/laserscan_multi_merger]
Publications: 
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /merged_cloud [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /scan_multi [sensor_msgs/LaserScan]

Subscriptions: 
 * /tf [unknown type]
 * /tf_static [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/get_loggers
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/set_logger_level
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/set_parameters


contacting node http://******-***002:******/ ...
Pid: 9156
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

when Node is working:

```
roslaunch ira_laser_tools laserscan_multi_merger.launch 
... logging to /home/bchan/.ros/log/d6143206-e867-11ea-8f07-10653056d93e/roslaunch-*****-*****-*****.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://***PC-******:*****/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/angle_increment: 0.0058
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/angle_max: 2.0
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/angle_min: -2.0
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/cloud_destination_topic: /merged_cloud
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/destination_frame: Lidar_merge
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/laserscan_topics: /sensor_1/points ...
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/range_max: 50.0
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/range_min: 0.3
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/scan_destination_topic: /scan_multi
 * /laserscan_multi_merger/scan_time: 0.0333333
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /
    laserscan_multi_merger (ira_laser_tools/laserscan_multi_merger)
```

Thanks for help in advance!!!!
If there any other options available like ira_merger tool.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360477/ira_laser_tools-merger-node-is-not-subscribing-lidar-topics/) by [p18dhavan](https://answers.ros.org/users/58679/p18dhavan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems provided topic names in launch file does not match existing topic names:

provided in config topic: /laserscan_multi_merger/laserscan_topics: /sensor_1/points

existing topic:  /sensor1/points

So "sensor_1" does not match "sensor1".

Based on [module source code](https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools/blob/master/src/laserscan_multi_merger.cpp) this module works only with sensor_msgs/LaserScan. Please make sure you are trying to merge laserscans but not point clouds.

The module makes validation of data types before subscription and existence of topics by provided names. It's not quite usual design in ros modules and allows this module to wait for correct topics silently (you don't see subscriptions in ros node info output).

---

Originally posted by [dtyugin](https://answers.ros.org/users/58330/dtyugin/) with karma: 121 on 2020-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [p18dhavan](https://answers.ros.org/users/58679/p18dhavan/) on 2020-08-27**:
Thank you for your suggestion. Do you have any recommendation for point cloud lidar merger?

**Comment by [dtyugin](https://answers.ros.org/users/58330/dtyugin/) on 2020-08-28**:
Well, you can try point cloud merger from [autoware](https://github.com/Autoware-AI/core_perception/blob/master/points_preprocessor/nodes/points_concat_filter/points_concat_filter.cpp). I don't use it but looking into source code there are no autoware specific dependencies, so you can take only merger node from the whole project. Or you can build the whole autoware project and run this node.